# Lodash, taking objects fulfilling requirements

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

Example:

```
Animals = [{Name: 'Dog', Id: 0},
           {Name: 'Cat', Id: 1},
           {Name: 'Mouse', Id: null}]
```

How to take all objects where Id isn't null into new array?

Expected output:

```
NewArray = [{Name: 'Dog', Id: 0},
            {Name: 'Cat', Id: 1}]
```

Comment: can you also tell the expected output

Comment: Depends, do you want to change that array or return a new one?

Comment: Edited first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter)

```js
var Animals = [{Name: 'Dog', Id: 0},{Name: 'Cat', Id: 1},{Name: 'Mouse', Id:null}]
var newArray =_.filter(Animals ,a=> a.Id != null)
console.log(newArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or if they want to mutate the current array, use [`_.remove`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove)

Comment: And how to do that using lodash?

Comment: @ChrisK. use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter). would be pretty much the same as the code above. `_.filter(Animals , a=> a.Id != null)`

Comment: @ChrisK. see my updated answer.i was  updated with lodash